# Angular - Nested ngFor

Tags: angular, nested, ngfor

I need to iterate over an array with nested arrays inside and display inputs by it. Heres my approach:

```js
<div *ngFor = "let arrobject of Array">
     <div *ngFor = "let innerObject of arrobject">
          <input type="text">
     </div>
</div>
```

Tried with `ng-container` as well:

```js
<ng-container *ngFor = "let arrobject of Array">
     <ng-container*ngFor = "let innerObject of arrobject">
          <input type="text">
     </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The *inputs* are generated correctly but the problem is that I can't `focus` on.

Comment: *"I need to iterate over a big object"* - `*ngFor` supports only arrays.

Comment: Yeah I ment arrays. thanks.

Comment: In angular2 it is not possible to iterate with ngFor via object

Comment: @YordanNikolov yeah been told that already... it was a mistake I'm talking about an array.

Comment: Mind to create a small plunker to reproduce this issue?

Comment: what is your array can you post a part of the same